# Using .pivot() after saving and loading from CSV causes KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, keyerror

I am trying to pull data from Yahoo! Finance for analysis and am having trouble when I want to read from a CSV file instead of downloading from Yahoo! every time I run the program.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime

def get(tickers, startdate, enddate):
    def data(ticker):
        return pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start = startdate, end = enddate)
    datas = map(data, tickers)
    return(pd.concat(datas, keys = tickers, names = ['Ticker', 'Date']))

tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG']

all_data = get(tickers, datetime.datetime(2006, 10,1), datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 7))
all_data.to_csv('data/alldata.csv')

#Open file
all_data_csv = pd.read_csv('data/alldata.csv', header = 0, index_col = 'Date', parse_dates = True)

daily_close = all_data[['Adj Close']].reset_index().pivot('Date', 'Ticker', 'Adj Close')
```

I'm having problems with the 'daily_close' section. The above code works as it is using 'all_data' which comes directly from the web. How do I alter the bottom line of code so that the data is being pulled from my csv file? I have tried `daily_close = all_data_csv[['Adj Close']].reset_index().pivot('Date', 'Ticker', 'Adj Close')` however this results in a KeyError due to 'Ticker'.

The csv data is in the following format, with the first column containing all of the tickers:

[image]

Comment: `all_data_csv.reset_index('Date')[['Date', 'Ticker', 'Adj Close']].pivot('Date', 'Ticker', 'Adj Close')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code for `all_data_csv` will not work as it did for `all_data`. This is a consequence of the fact that `all_data` contains a `MultiIndex` with all the information needed to carry out the pivot.

However, in the case of `all_data_csv`, the only index is `Date`. So, we'd need to do a little extra in order to get this to work.

1. First, reset the `Date` index
2. Select only the columns you need - `['Date', 'Ticker', 'Adj Close']`
3. Now, pivot on these columns

```
c = ['Date', 'Ticker', 'Adj Close']
daily_close = all_data_csv.reset_index('Date')[c].pivot(*c)

daily_close.head()

Ticker          AAPL        GOOG       MSFT
Date                                       
2006-10-02  9.586717  199.422943  20.971155
2006-10-03  9.486828  200.714539  20.978823
2006-10-04  9.653308  206.506866  21.415722
2006-10-05  9.582876  204.574448  21.400393
2006-10-06  9.504756  208.891357  21.362070
```